# Log4j configuration with different logger level for the same class or package

Tags: java, logging, log4j, axis

Nowadays I am using AXIS client to conect with some Webservices. I have configured the logger level at log4j properties like this:

org.apache.axis.client=INFO

However, I would need to config diferent logger level for this client depending from what class or method use the AXIS client.

Is there any possibility to configure log4j with this purpose?

Answer (score -1):

A solution to log the Axis Faults is extend the OnFault method :

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.axis.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler;

public class SOAPLogHandler extends BasicHandler {

  private static final String AXIS = "AXIS";
  private static final String AXIS_FAULT = "AXIS FAULT";
  private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SOAPLogHandler.class);
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

  @Override
  public void invoke(MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
    logMessage(AXIS, msgContext);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFault(MessageContext msgContext) {
    try {            
        logMessage(AXIS_FAULT,msgContext);
    } catch (AxisFault axisFault) {
        LOG.error("Error on logging messages ",axisFault);
    }
  }

  private void logMessage(String preamble, MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
    if (msgContext.getResponseMessage() != null && msgContext.getResponseMessage().getSOAPPart() != null) {
        LOG.info("{} Response ={}",preamble ,msgContext.getResponseMessage().getSOAPPartAsString());
        return;
    }

    if (msgContext.getRequestMessage() != null && msgContext.getRequestMessage().getSOAPPartAsString() != null) {
        LOG.info("{} Request={}",preamble,msgContext.getRequestMessage().getSOAPPartAsString());
    }
  }
}
```

It is also mandatory to set the handler in the global configuration request flow, in the wsdd file will be something like this :

```
<globalConfiguration>     
  <requestFlow>
    <handler type="log" />
  </requestFlow>
  <responseFlow>
    <handler type="log" />
  </responseFlow>
</globalConfiguration>

<handler name="log" type="java:your.package.SOAPLogHandler"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is fine to control AxisFault. 

However, I am looking for controlling the logger level of any AXIS request or response and depending on the WS, force the level to INFO or to ERROR.

¿May I do this with a genereic SoapHandler getting the SoapAction?

Comment: yes, you can modify the above one be as "SoapAction"